# In what cases is it a better choice to return a response than to edit the HttpServletResponse?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've currently found out three ways to write responses for endpoints in a `@RestController` annotated class:

```
@RestController
public class StringController {

    @GetMapping("/1")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getString1(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>( new ArrayList<>(
                Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D")
        ), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST );
    }

    @GetMapping("/2")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public List<String> getString2(){
        return new ArrayList<>(
                Arrays.asList( "E", "F", "G", "H" ) );
    }

    @GetMapping("/3")
    public void getString3(HttpServletResponse response ) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(  );
        response.setContentType( "application/json" );
        response.setStatus( 321 );
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( "E", "F", "G", "H" ) );
        mapper.writeValue( response.getOutputStream(), list );
    }

}
```

For methods 1 and 2, they're simply returning a response. I wouldn't really ask about between the two since I think `@ResponseStatus` is simply just a newer addition.
But as for method 3, it does not return a response, rather it edits the very response itself via `HttpServletResponse`. **In what cases is it a better choice to create and return a new response than to edit the `HttpServletResponse`?**

*P.S. I know my status codes are all wrong, I was simply experimenting with them.*

Comment: Something like method 3 would make sense when your response is too large to fit in memory and you want to stream it rather than store and forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are Spring specific functionality. If you're not using Spring, you have to use `HttpServletResponse` directly (assuming you're not using another framework).

As you see, the code looks more readable when you can see the status code and response type directly from the method instead of having to look inside.

So the rule of thumb is, don't use `HttpServletResponse` directly unless you need to, and you shouldn't need to do it very often. There's nothing bad about it, but it's cleaner to code with Spring's annotations.